# Looking for qrels file of TREC Million Query Track and Web Track queries

Tags: freebase

I am using annotation TREC queries (TREC Million Query Track and Web Track queries) from [this page](http://lemurproject.org/clueweb09/related-data.php) . I could not find qrel files for evaluation my result of these queries. I just find [this page](http://trec.nist.gov/data/web2011.html) which have qrels file related to **clueweb09** dataset.

Could you please inform me where can I find them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Prel files. They are judgment files too and trec-eval accept them as input.However, they contains different information.